# The "Current Figure" is often mentioned in matplotlib, but what actually IS the current figure?

Tags: python, matplotlib

`matplotlib.pyplot.gcf()`
Gets the *current figure*.

But if you have multiple figures, how do you know which one is the *current one?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentations, gcf() will get the current figure from pyplot figure stack. As stack works in LIFO(Last in first out) manner. The current figure will be that figure which you have made most recently.

Comment: That is very helpful, thanks. This actually brings up a follow up question. If there exists a pyplot figure stack, does that mean we can reference figures that are NOT the current figure, but figures from before?

Comment: Welcome, look I don't know that clearly but I suppose we cannot do that, we can see the number of figures present in the stack by using get_fignums() method, but we cannot reference the previous figures, otherwise there is no use of using a stack (as LIFO mechanism is not being followed here).

Comment: You don’t need to try on the stack at all. You can reference figures by their figure number plt.figure(num).  Even better you can keep references to the figures yourself: myfigref=plt.figure()